# Code for debug mode is not compiled when publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish, preprocessor-directive, debug-mode

There're places where I use `#if DEBUG` compiler directive to choose which code to compile. Until just a little while ago I was able to publish my ASP.NET MVC application in either Debug or Release mode. In fact I can still do that. But now, for some reason, no matter which mode I choose I get only the Release code in the output. If I take a look inside the generated dll with .NET Reflector, I can see that the code after `#if DEBUG` is not present. 
 I've checked the `Define DEBUG constant` for Debug mode in project properties. The only way I can get it work is to define DEBUG constant explicitly. Is there any other place where I can configure publish settings besides the one when publishing?

Comment: In project properties, under the Build tab, do you have "Define DEBUG constant" checked for the debug configuration?

Comment: @DavidG, yes sure. I've stated that in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lot's of digging (and right after posting this question), I found a file called MyProjectName.pubxml under ProjectName|Properties|PublishProfiles:

[image]

There I found this line:

```
   <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
```

After setting this to True, it finally got solved and works as expected. I also noticed that the value for `LastUsedBuildConfiguration` was Release although it was Debug in fact.So obviously this file failed to be up-to-date at some point. Hope this helps those who are candidates to waste hours of time in time.

**EDIT**

I faced the same problem again but this time I needed the reverse, the publish mode. Changing the above mentioned file didn't solve the problem this time. So I decided to do what I think would be the best thing to do: Just remove the PublishProfiles folder so that you are prompted to create a new publish profile when you try to publish your application the next time. That solved the problem.

**EDIT2**

Man, I didn't realize that there was an option to choose a configuration. Comes out we need to choose which configuration we need to publish to no matter what configuration is chosen in the visual studio itself.

[image]

Comment: That's a nice catch. Been driving me nuts. Thank you.